# jquery .submit() not passing value to action page

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to load the content of the php page in the div "content", using .submit in jquery. i am facing a problem that when i press the submit btn the values dont get passed to the action page. here is the form code

```
<form id="f1" action="attandace/students/take_attandance.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label id="sb">Subject Name</label></td>
            <td>
                <select id="s_b" name="subject_name">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <?php echo $option; ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><label id="cn">Class Name</label></td>
            <td>
                <select id="c_n" name="class_name">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <?php echo $option2; ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><div align="center"><input id="btn" type="submit" name="tk" value="Take Attandance" /> 
           </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) 
{
    $('form').submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('action'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the values along using the `data` argument.

You can make use of [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) for it.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray());
    });
});
```